# JOOQ - How to create primary key

Tags: java, jooq

don't you know how to create primary key in JOOQ (Java) ?
What i need  is just get correct string of create table.
I have yet this fragment of code (using SQLDialect.MYSQL):

```
public void createTable(String tableName, Map<String, DataType> columns){
        this.tableName = tableName;
        table = ctx.createTable(tableName).column("id", INTEGER.identity(true));

        System.out.println(table.getSQL() + ";");
}
```

OUTPUT (from string builder):

```
create table `filetest`(`id` int not null auto_increment);
```

And what I need is to set primary key to get correct output:

```
create table `filetest`(`id` int not null auto_increment, primary key ('id'));
```

Is it possible, without execute() ? Because I need only it as string, so I would like to use again only getSQL() command...

I found something like this: DSL.primaryKey("id");

But I cannot to connect it with rest. It means that when I call getSQL() it is not there, I could just system out it at the end of method, but it wont be inside of rest CREATE sql... I hope you understand what I want to say.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add constraints with jooq to the [create statement](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-building/ddl-statements/create-statement/).

As example:

```
DSLContext ctx;

String createTableSql = ctx.createTable("TABLE_NAME")
        .column("TABLE_ID", SQLDataType.BIGINT.identity(true))
        .column("COL_1", SQLDataType.VARCHAR(64).nullable(false))
        .constraints(
            DSL.constraint("PK_TABLE").primaryKey("TABLE_ID"),
            DSL.constraint("UNIQUE_COL_1").unique("COL_1")
        ).getSQL();

System.out.println(createTableSql);
```

Would create this statement:

```
create table `TABLE_NAME`(
    `TABLE_ID` bigint not null auto_increment, 
    `COL_1` varchar(64) not null, 
    constraint `PK_TABLE` primary key (`TABLE_ID`), 
    constraint `UNIQUE_COL_1` unique (`COL_1`)
)
```